# codeigniter pass array to query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to pass an array to a model which has a query. I'm not sure how to correctly pass the array or if i have to manipulate the array somehow.

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

I have a controller with this line:

```
$ratings = $this->login_model->get_ratings($mechanicIds);   // get the mechanic ratings
```

I have this model:

```
  function get_ratings($mechanicId)
    {
        $sql = "select m.mechanic_id, 
                   m.mechanic_name, 
                   m.city, 
                   m.state, 
                   count(mr.rating_id) as num_ratings, 
                   round(avg(mr.rating_id),2) avg_rating
                from mechanic m, mechanic_rating mr, rating r
                where m.mechanic_id in (?)
                and m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
                and mr.rating_id = r.rating_id";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $mechanicId);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It actually returns results, but the problem is it only returns the results 1 row when it should be returning 2 since there are 2 results in my array. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The elements in the array, are they being used in WHERE clause in the query?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to use them on the line "Where m.mechanic in (?)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question which helped.

Below is the code I used.

Controller that contains this:

```
                $mIds_size = count($mIds);
                $i = 1;

                foreach($mIds as $row)
                {
                    if($i == $mIds_size)
                    {
                        $mechanicIds .= $row;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $mechanicIds .= $row.', ';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

                $ratings = $this->login_model->get_ratings($mechanicIds);   // get the mechanic ratings
```

Model which contains this:

```
    function get_ratings($mechanicId)
    {

        $this->db->escape($mechanicId);

        $sql = "select m.mechanic_id, 
                       m.mechanic_name, 
                       m.city, 
                       m.state, 
                       count(mr.rating_id) as num_ratings, 
                       round(avg(mr.rating_id),2) avg_rating
                from mechanic m, mechanic_rating mr, rating r
                where m.mechanic_id in ($mechanicId)
                and m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
                and mr.rating_id = r.rating_id
                group by mechanic_id";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $mechanicId);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your foreach loop is EXACTLY equal to `implode(', ', $mIds);`

Comment: This is an older question so it's not fresh in my head, but did you read the comments to your answer? It doesn't work because it puts single quotes around all the elements combined.

Comment: I understand, Codeigniter is probably auto escaping the value that it is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $mechanicId);
```

to this:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(implode(', ',$mechanicId)));
```

as per [the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: I had this at one point, but it was only returning one result. After playing with your answer i realized it was because I didn't have a group by clause in my query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok i guess it's not working. When i run the query in mysql using "Where m.mechanic in (1, 2)", i get 2 rows. When i try the same query in my program except i use the line "Where m.mechanic in (?)", it only gives me 1 result.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, i bet it's expecting another question mark to use the second element in the array.

Comment: @Catfish. implode(',',$mechanicID) will turn the array into one comma separated string, you only need one placeholder

Comment: It was putting single quotes around that array so it was only getting the first value. My answer below seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK. It will produce something like `IN('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10')`. Which is a single string, not an array.

Comment: Which is exactly what should be used in an `ÌN` clause. Please read the "Query Bindings" part of the documentation I linked to

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array into a raw query (not built with helper methods) for an `IN` condition, use the `?` placeholder without wrapping in parentheses.

When binding the array to the placeholder, you must declare your array inside of an array.  In other words, the "parameters" (2nd) argument of `query()` method expects an array which relates to each `?` in the SQL string.  Because the first `?` is bound to an array, the `$mechanicIds` array must be declared as the first element of the "parameters" argument.  I have tested this advice to work successfully in a CodeIgniter3 instance that I have access to.

```
$sql = "SELECT m.mechanic_id, 
               m.mechanic_name, 
               m.city, 
               m.state, 
               COUNT(mr.rating_id)         AS num_ratings, 
               ROUND(AVG(mr.rating_id), 2) AS avg_rating
        FROM mechanic        AS m,
             mechanic_rating AS mr,
             rating          AS r
        WHERE m.mechanic_id IN ?                            /* <--- here */
          AND m.mechanic_id = mr.mechanic_id
          AND mr.rating_id = r.rating_id";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, [$mechanicIds]);
```

The DB_driver.php core file contains this portion of code in `compile_binds()` which  escapes each value in the array and wraps the comma-joined string in parentheses before returning the sql string.

```
...
do
{
    $c--;
    $escaped_value = $this->escape($binds[$c]);
    if (is_array($escaped_value))
    {
        $escaped_value = '('.implode(',', $escaped_value).')';
    }
    $sql = substr_replace($sql, $escaped_value, $matches[0][$c][1], $ml);
}
while ($c !== 0);
...
```